# UK visa submission after biometric scanning

Tags: visas, uk

I am a green card holder living in America. I am planning to go to Scotland. I have completed all the documents except, am waiting for the employment letter which will be ready by tomorrow i.e., Thursday Sep 12th. UK visa submission rules state that "The visa application must be submitted no earlier than 24-36 hours after and no later than 2 weeks after biometric submission. "

I have completed my biometric scanning on the afternoon of Friday, Aug, 30 at about 1PM. I am planning to do overnight shipping of my application tomorrow i.e., Thursday Sep 12th. Friday, Sep, 13th will be final day of the 2nd week. So, I am wondering if it is still OK to send the applications tomorrow.

Comment: Not to appear condescending but what's your alternative?

Comment: @Karlson Even if your demeanor is not commendable, I will respond to you. I am wondering if I should still send the application or Is my effort futile, meaning will they consider processing my application? or should I start filing a new application.

Comment: My personal philosophy is that if you don't have to rush don't.  They might accept your application or they might not.  If you are no worse off with a new application start a new application.  Just my opinion on the problem.

Comment: @Karlson Looks like from the website http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/visas-immigration/general-info/processing-times/#resultTableAnchor, 97% of the applications are processed in 15 days and 99% in 40 days. I have little more than 6 weeks. I am going on November 6th. After the documents and sent and are processed, do they ask for my passport to be sent to them so that they can stamp the passport or will they send a sticker stamp so that I can put it on my passport? One of my colleagues said for Canada, they ask for passport to be mailed to them.

Comment: I'd call the consulate to find out.

Comment: You might find this website very useful www.expatforum.com - if you go to the "Britain" forum, you will find people's experiences similar to yours and there is also a visa timeline thread which is interesting to look through to see how other people have fared time-wise. There are also some moderators on there who have expert knowledge and tend to reply quite quickly - if one of the other members doesn't get there before them!

Comment: @Karlson Thanks for the advice for calling the consulate, I have to send an original passport and a copy of it. I also had to send a color copy of the green card which I didn't know about. and about the question, consulate people said as long as it reaches by tomorrow, they will consider the application.

Comment: @Karlson might be worth putting that as an answer, as it's really what people should do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally if there are no ill effects to resubmitting your application then I would do it.

Now as far as you sending your application a day before the deadline you should contact the consulate as to what they will do.  It is more likely than not they will accept it but this needs to be verified at the consulate you're sending it to.

So an exact answer can only be given by the consulate.